# How to make a HTML5 spinning list/rotating wheel selector/picker

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

My question is about an answer given by user ByteHamster here: [How to create JavaScript/HTML5 Spinner List with images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481603/how-to-create-javascipt-html5-spinner-list-with-images) in the answer he/she gives an example of how to create a scrolling animation with html, css and Javascript. The animation allows the user to scroll through the numbers by clicking above or below the selected number on screen, and the selected number is shown in a div below the animation.

I was wondering if it’s possible to do something similar to this but instead of having an image moving up and down, can it be turned into a number wheel? By that I mean, in the example above, the scrolling stops in one direction once the number reaches 0, I’m wondering if it’s possible to create a wheel, where a user could constantly spin it from top to bottom, or bottom to top if they wished to do so. Would this require using 3d interactive animation software?

I've seen this question: [HTML5/CSS3 - how to make "endless" rotating background - 360 degrees panorama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170173/html5-css3-how-to-make-endless-rotating-background-360-degrees-panorama) but I'm unsure if the answers are applicable to my project as they don't seem to be interactive.

As user ByteHamster's answer is over 3 years old, I was wondering if there’s a better way to achieve this effect with a html5 animation? And am I correct in thinking that the Javascript in the example would make it not work on some devices/browsers that don’t have Javascript enabled? Would a html5 approach be the best way to ensure the effect works on most devices/browsers?

Comment: Could you describe the expected result a bit more - should it be vertical or horizontal? I made a small plugin to do animated scrolling with `requestAnimationFrame`, are the boxes that resemble a slot machine similar to what you are after? If you want any event interaction, JavaScript will definitely be needed. But only a fraction of a percentage of users will have it disabled. http://ataredo.com/morphology/lucidscroll/

Comment: Hi @shikkediel thanks for your reply. The result I'm looking for is a vertical wheel-like effect. It is similar to how a dial on a slot machine rotates, imagine looking at one of the wheels from this image face on: http://www.theresasheridan.com/wp-content/uploads/images/number-wheel-300x224.jpg the wheel has the numbers 0 to 9 on it, and as the user clicks/drags the wheel in either direction (up or down) the wheel rotates vertically so show a different number facing the viewer.

Comment: For example, if the number facing the viewer is 5, and the viewer clicks below the 5 (or clicks on the wheel and drags it downwards (on touchscreen devices)) then the wheel should rotate and rest with the 4 facing the viewer. I hope I've clarified what I'm trying to achieve, thanks again for your advice.

Comment: So if I get it correctly it would be like the first link in your question but infinite and only showing a single number at a time - also just a front view, no perspective? Maybe just some nice graphics to make it appear that way. I think using the mousewheel instead might be nicer, mobile devices would need special treatment with a custom swipe script. Probably not really like this forum to post complete code but I may have a go at it, if it's alright to use jQuery. One more question... should the scroll be animated like the plugin I linked to or can it be an instantaneous switch?

Comment: Yes it would be like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhdsssbr/ except infinite, meaning the user could move from the number 9 to the number 1 in two moves (9, 0, 1), instead of the number list having two ends it would be infinite like a real 3d wheel. I would love to have something that was a 3d animation of this but I'm afraid that's out of my skill level, I thought a 2d interactive animation might be as effective, I was curious if it's possible to apply some perspective by showing half of the previous number and half of the next number above and below the selected number, while...

Comment: I'll have a look if I can create the basic functionality. Perspective could always be added later with CSS. Could you answer my last two question there though - about using the jQuery library and the fact if the rotation should be smooth or instantaneous? The latter is much easier, the former a bit nicer but a lot more code - I may have to use the prefabricated plugin for that.

Comment: ...tilting them backwards so that it looks like they're stuck onto the surface of a real wheel, but I don't know if that kind of image manipulation is possible with css? I thought if that wasn't possible then maybe a slight shadow at the top and bottom might give a similar, if not as impressive, effect. I'm not sure how to apply specific mousewheel functionality, or how to apply the swipe script effect, would adding that functionality complicate the process a lot?

Comment: Sorry :) it takes me a while to formulate what I want to say into comments. I would like the scroll to be a smooth animation to give the appearance that it's a real wheel turning if it's possible to do that. Is jQuery something that will work on all browsers that have Javascript enabled? If so that sounds perfect, thanks for the link to your site, and thank you so much for your help with this, I'm really looking forward to seeing what you're able to do. Thank you again!

Comment: Working on it... could be a little while though. Wanna post it when it's good and finished.

Comment: Take as much time as you need, I'm just grateful for the help! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what I put together from the info provided... works with the mousewheel, swiping and clicking on the top and bottom numbers. Infinite as requested of course. No special perspective style (yet) but I thought it looked quite decent as is. Could still be an option naturally. Didn't use the plugin I linked to in the comments or `requestAnimationFrame` but jQuery `animate()` is quite a good tool for this. The library has great cross browser support (that's it's strength actually), all it needs is a link to it for the JavaScript to be able to get executed. You could use a CDN, this version also works for IE8- :

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For the best cross browser support on using the mousewheel, this plugin was included :

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

Just a basic parent and styling with spans for each number, a few prepended in case of going up.

```js
$(function() {

var gate = $(window),
cog = $('#rotator'),
digit = cog.find('span'),
field = $('#result'),
slot = digit.height(),
base = 1.5*slot,
up, swipe;

if (document.readyState == 'complete') interAction();
else gate.one('load', interAction);

function interAction() {

 field.text(0);

 cog.scrollTop(base).fadeTo(0,1).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

  if (isBusy()) return false;

  up = delta > 0;
  nextNumber();

  return false;
 });

 digit.on('touchstart', function(e) {

  var begin = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

  digit.on('touchmove', function(e) {

   var yaw = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY-begin;
   up = yaw < 0;
   swipe = Math.abs(yaw) > 30;
  });

  gate.one('touchend', function() {

   digit.off('touchmove');

   if (swipe && !isBusy()) nextNumber();
  });
 })
 .on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {

  if (e.which && e.which != 1) return;

  var zest = this, item = $(this).index();

  $(this).one('mouseup touchend', function(e) {

   digit.off('mouseup');

   var quit = e.originalEvent.changedTouches;

   if (quit) var jab = document.elementFromPoint(quit[0].clientX, quit[0].clientY);
   if (swipe || item == 2 || quit && jab != zest || isBusy()) return;

   up = item == 1;
   nextNumber();
  });

  return false;
 })
 .mouseleave(function() {

  digit.off('mouseup');
 });
}

function isBusy() {

 return cog.is(':animated');
}

function nextNumber() {

 var aim = base;
 swipe = false;

 up ? aim += slot : aim -= slot;

 cog.animate({scrollTop: aim}, 250, function() {

  up ? digit.eq(0).appendTo(cog) : digit.eq(9).prependTo(cog);

  digit = cog.find('span');

  cog.scrollTop(base);
  field.text(digit.eq(2).text());
 });
}
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

#ticker {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#rotator {
  height: 140px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-image:
  url(http://ataredo.com/external/image/flip.png),
  url(http://ataredo.com/external/image/flip.png),
  url(http://ataredo.com/external/image/flip.png);
  background-position: 0 0, 50% 50%, 100% 150%;
  background-size: 300% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#rotator span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#result {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<div id="ticker">
 <div id="rotator">
   <span>8</span>
   <span>9</span>
   <span>0</span>
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
   <span>4</span>
   <span>5</span>
   <span>6</span>
   <span>7</span>
 </div>
 <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Pretty straightforward, animates the scroll position up or down and then appends or prepends the first or last number depending on the direction. The duration of the animation can be set here :

```
cog.animate({scrollTop: current}, 250, function() {
```

---

Updated - after having some new insights, for example the `touchend` event always firing on the original element, I've overhauled the code. Besides that, it now has a sprite background that will stay in proportion with the size of the numbers themselves. Also improved the overall logic and removed a nested listener glitch.

Another reason for this edit is to insert a demo that allows to have multiple tickers (and preset the numbers). As I've even moved on beyond that (adding direct response functionality), I thought it would be a good idea to leave the minimal working code for that here as well:

```js
$(function() {

var gate = $(window),
orb = document,
cog = $('.rotator'),
field = $('#result'),
slot = cog.height()/2,
base = 1.5*slot,
list = [],
niche = [7,7,7],
term = 250, // duration of animation
mass, up = true,
yaw = 'mousemove.ambit touchmove.ambit',
hike = 'mouseup.turf touchend.turf',
part = 'mouseleave.range';

tallyCells();

if (orb.readyState == 'complete') interAction();
else gate.one('load', interAction);

gate.on('mouseleave touchcancel', function(e) {

 !(e.type == 'mouseleave' && e.relatedTarget) && lotRelease();
});

function interAction() {

cog.scrollTop(base).each(function(unit) {

 var pinion = $(this),
 digit = pinion.find('.quota'),
 cipher = Number(niche[unit])%10 || 0;
 list[unit] = digit;
 niche[unit] = 0;
 field.append(0);

 for (var i = 0; i < cipher; i++) nextNumber(pinion, unit, true);

 pinion.mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

  if (isBusy(pinion)) return false;

  up = delta > 0;
  nextNumber(pinion, unit);

  return false;
 });

 digit.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {

  if (e.which && e.which != 1) return;

  var zest = this, ken = {}, item = $(this).index();

  tagPoints(e, ken);

  digit.on(part, wipeSlate).on(hike, function(e) {

   wipeSlate();

   var quit = e.originalEvent.changedTouches;

   if (quit) var jab = orb.elementFromPoint(quit[0].clientX, quit[0].clientY);
   if (item == 2 || quit && jab != zest || isBusy(pinion)) return;

   up = item == 1;
   nextNumber(pinion, unit);
  });

  gate.on(yaw, function(e) {

   hubTrace(e, ken);
  })
  .on(hike, function() {

   lotRelease();

   if (!ken.hit || isBusy(pinion)) return;

   up = ken.way < 0;
   nextNumber(pinion, unit);
  });

  return false;
 });

}).fadeTo(0,1);

function tagPoints(act, bit) {

 var nod = act.originalEvent.touches;
 bit.mark = nod ? nod[0].pageY : act.pageY;
 bit.veer = false;
}

function hubTrace(task, gob) {

 var peg = task.originalEvent.touches,
 fly = peg ? peg[0].pageY : task.pageY;
 gob.way = fly-gob.mark;
 gob.hit = Math.abs(gob.way) > 30;

 if (!gob.veer && gob.hit) {
 gob.veer = true;
 wipeSlate();
 }
}

function wipeSlate() {

 mass.off(part + ' ' + hike);
}

function isBusy(whirl) {

 return whirl.is(':animated');
}

function nextNumber(aim, knob, quick) {

 var intent = base, hook = list[knob];

 up ? intent += slot : intent -= slot;

 if (quick) {
 aim.scrollTop(intent);
 revolveTooth();
 }
 else aim.animate({scrollTop: intent}, term, revolveTooth);

function revolveTooth() {

 up ? hook.eq(0).appendTo(aim) : hook.eq(9).prependTo(aim);

 list[knob] = aim.find('.quota');
 niche[knob] = Number(list[knob].eq(2).text());

 aim.scrollTop(base);
 field.text(niche.join(''));
}
}
}

function lotRelease() {

 gate.off(yaw).add(mass).off(hike);
 mass.off(part);
}

function tallyCells() {

 cog.each(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  var n; !i ? n = 8 : (i == 1 ? n = 9 : n = i-2);

  $(this).append('<div></div>').find('div').eq(i).text(n).addClass('quota');
  }
 });

 mass = $('.quota');
}
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
}

#ticker, .rotator {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rotator {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background-image:
  url(http://ataredo.com/external/image/flip.png),
  url(http://ataredo.com/external/image/flip.png),
  url(http://ataredo.com/external/image/flip.png);
  background-position: 0 0, 50% 50%, 100% 150%;
  background-size: 300% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.quota {
  height: 50%;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#result {
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<div id="ticker">
  <div class="rotator"></div>
  <div class="rotator"></div>
  <div class="rotator"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

It will populate the numbers automatically so there's no need to write the markup. Responds to mouse dragging as well.

---

The latest evolution of the script can be found here :

[codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/avVJdG](https://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/avVJdG?editors=001)

---

Final update - a 3d version that uses `transition` instead of jQuery `.animate`. The wheel is made up of individually rotated elements around the x-axis, creating a basically infinite decagon without the need for prepending or appending elements:

[codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/qpjGyq](https://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/qpjGyq?editors=001)

The cogs are "flickable", making them progress at the speed that the user gives them - then stop again when clicking. They also respond much quicker to mouse wheel events than the original demo. Both reasons why I've left out click events, as opposed to the earlier scripts. Browser support is also a bit more limited but good nonetheless - I've made an extra effort to make it IE10+ compatible.

Comment: That’s amazing! It’s working really well! The ``touchstart`` seems to be very fast/responsive , I’m really curious to see how it would look with swipe support on my phone and tablet, would it be possible to add this to your example as well if it’s not too much trouble?

Comment: I’m not sure what the wheel event is, would its effect look much different than what you’ve currently made? If it’s a relatively new thing does that mean that older browsers wouldn’t be able to use it? Ideally I’d like the method used to move the wheel to be widely supported across all browsers and devices, and to keep being supported going into the future.

Comment: I was wondering, with your example, is it possible to grab the selected number and send it to my database? By this I mean that I’d like to have a div below the wheel which contains a button that when pressed will send the selected number to my database by an ajax post linked to a php script. In the first example in my question the selected number was called 
“currentPosition”, and it was placed inside the div called “value” here: 
``currentPosition = targetPosition;
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "Value: " + currentPosition;``...

Comment: the number appearing in this div ("value") would change automatically whenever the wheel was moved.

I’m able to send the contents of this div to my database on click of a “submit” button, but I was wondering what the equivalent of ``currentPosition`` is in your code? Thanks so much again for your help, it looks great!

Comment: Looked at it closely and think all requirements are incorporated in the update... but been tweaking it a bit since I posted that. I may need to make another edit to the answer but I'll do that when there's *nothing* left to be changed. I'd really like to leave a good script here but don't wanna overdo it either.

Comment: By the way, mousewheeling may seem counterintuitive compared to page scrolling but I was looking at it from the perspective of an actual wheel. Reversing the direction would be as simple as changing `<` into `>` on this line inside the event listener of course : `if (delta < 0) up = true;`.

Comment: Hi @shikkediel that's brilliant, it's looking really good and working really well. Take as much time as you need if you need to edit it again, I'm looking forward to seeing how the multiple tickers will look like. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Cheers, you're very welcome. Interesting to put this together, it actually had two small flaws that made it apparently work well with touch events but it was not quite as intended. Combining clicks with swipes was a bit trickier than I thought. But it should be all good now, made some other minor improvements too. I'll leave this post alone then from any further edits but will definitely keep working on the multiple ticker.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'd be grateful if you could let me know if you make a multiple ticker too, I'd really like to see that, thanks again!

Comment: Looks like the multiple ticker is also working, @Emily. It has another advantage - you don't have to actually write the HTML, it will loop through the `.rotator` class and automatically fill them with the numbers.

Comment: Hi @shikkediel it looks great! I noticed one strange thing though, if you move a wheel up and down really fast a couple of times, the numbers sometimes get switched about. By that I mean when I was moving a wheel up and down I noticed that the 9 and 0 got switched, so that the face of the wheel read 0, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. I think it might be caused by the wheel being moved faster than the numbers get appended to it sometimes? In any case it looks really good, thank you again for working on this!

Comment: Hmm... that is strange. It was programmed to block any input until the animation has finished. Does this happen when using the mousewheel - and with any particular device (OS) maybe? Can't reproduce it here. Edit - I think I see what you mean, swiping may need a small tweak.

Comment: Hi, that's correct, I tested the swiping on two sony xperia phones running android gingerbread 2.3.3 and lollipop 5.0.2. I couldn't recreate it on my laptop with a touchpad or mouse though. It doesn't happen unless the swiping is really fast, but I thought I'd let you know in case there was an easy fix for it.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Made a small change that should prevent this from happening. Only thing I can't test myself is multi touch but I don't see anything obvious that might cause an issue. Cheers.

Comment: This looks like a really great piece of code... how do you initialize it?  You should make this a github project with downloadable source and some working examples.

Comment: Also, Also, $().mobiscroll seems to be an ionic function... I get two errors: $(...).mobiscroll is not a function and, on page load I get pinion.mousewheel is not a function.  Of course I included <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

Comment: I don't see that the jQuery library itself is being linked to in the fiddle. Indeed the mousewheel script is also needed but the link mentioned is a 404 not found. Both these scripts should be all to make the number picker work. I'm not exactly sure where `$().mobiscroll` would come in to be relevant for it...