# How to create a date picker scroll wheel in JS/HTML/CSS for a webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, figma

**My Goal**

I'm trying to achieve this scroll wheel/drumroll/ios date picker style element. It will be placed at the top and will switch the whole page, loading content from a given day. The page itself is scrollable, however I would also like the date picker wheel to be scrollable and draggable so it works for both desktop and mobile:

[image]

**What I've Found**

Here are some good examples of the functionality I'm looking for:

- https://demo.mobiscroll.com/fullscreen/datetime/mobile-desktop-usage (blocked behind paywall, also the element itself is not very customizable)
- https://www.plus-one.tech/vue-drumroll-datetime-picker/ (This one uses Vue.js)

Obviously the idea would be to have only one column, space out the date elements, and flip it horizontally as shown in the image above. These are the only working examples I have found that function on both Desktop and Mobile devices.

**What I've Tried**

Every other example I have come across uses a framework or is built for iOS/Android only. I tried replicating the effect by modifying a carousel I found on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/T0RR1N/udxafzm1/2/

I've modified this JS section to detect scrolling, then change the carousel slides:

```
  window.onwheel = e => {
    if(e.deltaY >= 0){
      // Scrolling Down with mouse
      next();
    } else {
      // Scrolling Up with mouse
      prev();
    }
  }
```

I think this is the way to go, however there are several flaws with this approach:

1. The element scrolling mechanism breaks if you scroll to fast
2. List elements are deleted if they go off screen
3. The carousel doesn't pull from a list of existing elements

**My question**

What is the best way to implement this functionality using only JS, HTML, and CSS?

Any help is really appreciated, thank you for reading!

Comment: this stackover flow may be useful. The idea is the same as my answer though, set the overflow to hidden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157307/how-to-make-a-html5-spinning-list-rotating-wheel-selector-picker

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this, the basic idea is to set a div with a bunch of child divs and set the overflow to hidden then attach mouse up/down and mousemove events to the div and set the top based on whether the moved up or down. I didn't add boundary checks or any styling. You'll also have to fiddle with the scroll speed, right now I set it to 1px.

```html
<div style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;position:relative" id="carousel">
<div style="position:relative">op 1</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 2</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 3</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 4</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 5</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 6</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 7</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 8</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 9</div>
<div style="position:relative">op 10</div>
</div>

<script>

let dragged;
let mouseDown = false;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
    mouseDown = true;
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
    mouseDown = false;
});

document.getElementById("carousel").addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
if(mouseDown)
{
// store a ref. on the dragged elem
  dragged = event.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll("div");

  for (const node of dragged) {
  let position = parseFloat(node.style.top || 0);
  if(event.movementY > 0)
{  
    position = position - 1 + "px";
}
else{
    position = position + 1 + "px";
}
    node.style.top = position;
}
  }
});
</script>
```